# Function in C with unlimited arguments?

Tags: c

I want to define a function in C language which can take an unlimited number of arguments of  any datatype.
For example: `printf()`, `scanf()`, etc.

Any idea on this?

Comment: *Note: Probably best avoided where possible...

Comment: you cannot write a function which can take an "unlimited" number of arguments. There is always some upper limit. What you probably meant is, "variable" number of arguments.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To use variable number of arguments in C you need to include the header

```
#include <stdarg.h>
```

`printf()` in C is an example of function that takes variable number of arguments.

```
int printf(const char *fmt, ...)
```

More info [here](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter9/stdarg.html)

Comment: How can we access arguments in a random order? The link shows us only the way to access them sequentially.

Answer (score 7):

Declare the function as taking a `...` last argument.  You'll need to use the macros from `<stdarg.h>` to access the arguments as a `va_list`.

If you just want something "like `printf`, but with a little extra behavior", then you can pass the `va_list` to `vprintf`, `vfprintf`, or `vsprintf`.

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#ifdef __GNUC__
    __attribute__((format(printf, 1, 2)))
#endif
void PrintErrorMsg(const char* fmt, ...)
{
    time_t     now; 
    char       buffer[20];
    va_list    args;

    va_start(args, fmt);
    time(&now);
    strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime(&now));
    fprintf(stderr, "[%s] ", buffer);
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, args);
    fputc('\n', stderr);
    va_end(args);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
void printf(char* format, ...)
{
}
```

Look up [Variadic Functions](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Variadic-Functions.html) and `varargs.h` or `stdarg.h` (depending on the compiler).

Comment: There shouldn't be any compiler still in use that still requires `<varargs.h>`; all modern compilers (meaning less than about 10 years old) support `<stdarg.h>` and new code should only use that.  Note that some compilers no longer support `<varargs.h>`; I think I encountered this on HP-UX (by accident).

Answer (score 1):

See the `<stdarg.h>` header and related documentation.