# How can I build a function that can receive 3 or 4 arguments ?

Tags: c

I know it's a basic question ,

How can I build\write a function that can receive 3 or 4 arguments ?

Or more general , How can i write a function that can receive unknown number of arguments  ?

Thanks !

Comment: You can declare a variadic function. Surely Google could have informed you of that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Function in C with unlimited arguments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559791/function-in-c-with-unlimited-arguments)

Comment: WHHHHYYYY are you people upvoting this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To define a function with an unknown number of arguments the first one must be known. Then you have to include the `stdarg.h` library to access the arguments using it's functions: va_start, va_args, va_en and the type va_list.

In general the function is defined this way. Note that the first argument is not always of type `int`. It can be `const char *` for more controle on your arguments. for exemple in the `printf()` function.

```
type myFunction(int n, ...)
{
    int i;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, n);
    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
    // your argument is va_arg(args, int);
    //... do something with your aruments
    }
    va_end(args);
    // return your value
}
```

check these resources for more about `stdarg.h` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdarg/
or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdarg.h

Comment: Note: In Pre-C89, some `va_start()` used `va_start(args);` which allowed for `myFunction(...)`.  In such a case the number and type of args was derived via other means (e.g. global memory).  Much better to have "first one must be known".

Answer (score 4):

You need a function with a variadic parameter list. Use ellipses to define it:

```
void foo(int first, ...)
{
}
```

Use `var_args` to parse the parameters. The first parameter is usually used to

- address the other parameters
- control how the other parameters shall be treated

Answer (score 0):

For the more general aspect, you can store the arguments in an array. And you can then pass a pointer of the array or the array itself to the actual function. This permits you to manipulate those arguments.