# How can I access function arguments as an array?

Tags: c

I have a function in C, which takes a bunch of arguments, and I would like to treat those arguments like an array and access them by number.  For example, say I want to take 6 arguments plus a parameter from 1 to 6, and increment the corresponding argument.  I could do:

```
void myFunc(int arg1,int arg2,int arg3,int arg4,int arg5,int arg6,n)
{
if (n==1) ++arg1;
else if (n==2) ++arg2;
else if (n==3) ++arg3;
else if (n==4) ++arg4;
else if (n==5) ++arg5;
else if (n==6) ++arg6;
}
```

But that's a bit messy.  Is there a neater way to do this?

Comment: What does your real function actually do. Variable-length arguments in C are kind of fugly so maybe this isn't the best way to solve your real problem.

Comment: use an array as a function parameter?

Comment: Your function is a huge NOOP. All arguments of a function behave like local variables. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=c+function+array
@harper after the OP learns how to pass an array to a function via a pointer, it will no longer be a huge NOOP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I build a function that can receive 3 or 4 arguments ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20722299/how-can-i-build-a-function-that-can-receive-3-or-4-arguments)

Comment: A function that does `fn(int n, ...)` an uses var-args would seem to fit your requirements, though I warn you there will be no type checking on the subsequent variadic arg list, so tread carefully.

Answer (score 6):

Although as suggested in the comments passing a pointer to an array may be easier. If you really want to go with arguments then your best bet may be to use a variadric function:

```
void myFunc(int n, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    int arg;
    va_start(ap, n);
    while (--n)
        arg = va_arg(ap, int); /* Increments ap to the next argument. */
    va_end(ap);

    arg++;

}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd do it like this:

```
void myFunc(int n, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, n);

    int temp;
    for(n; n; --n)
    {
        temp = va_arg(vl, int);
    }

    temp++;
    va_end(args);
}
```

A few things to note:

- This does no handling if n == 0, and will be wrong in that case.
- Because C is *pass by value*, this will increment the variable locally, (as your original function), but the change will NOT take effect outside the function!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a temporary array of pointers to your arguments, then you can access them through this array of pointers:

```
void myFunc(int arg1,int arg2,int arg3,int arg4,int arg5,int arg6,n)
{
    int *array_of_args[] = {&arg1, &arg2, &arg3, &arg4, &arg5, &arg6};
    if (n >= 1 && n <= 6)
        ++*array_of_args[n - 1];
}
```

This is not better than your original code, but if your code uses the array-access several times, this hack will make the code smaller.

Comment: It's not a hack. It's structured and has well defined behavior. Much harder to break than the varargs options. You get a +1.

Comment: This is actually a great solution but the only problem is it only works if all the arguments are of the same type (or size in memory to be precise).

Answer (score 1):

Pass your arguments in as an array. Here I just used literals, but you could replace `1,2,3,4` with your own variables like `arg1, arg2`, and so on.

```
int myNumbers[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
myFunc(myNumbers, sizeof myNumbers / sizeof myNumbers[0]);
```

Then, your function needs to be prepared to accept the array. Also, rather than using six if's to check six arguments, we can write a for loop. However, that is entirely unrelated to the question and I understand you may be doing this for a class assignment.

```
void myFunc(int *args, int numArgs)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i; i < numArgs; i++)
    {
        if(args[i] == i+1) ++args[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Fixed all the errors, I hope. You had the right idea, but you really ought to compile and test code before you post it.

Comment: @abelenky Don't be so dismissive; a new user doesn't know the function of tags. Rather help or explain, that alienate people from SO.

Comment: @John This question is tagged with `c`, so the answer should be in `c` language.

Comment: @John, if you fix your errors, often times (and preferably) the down-voter will retract the down vote.  Your code still has an empty declaration:  `int[] myNumbers...`.  And the suggestion to test your code in your own C compiler before posting is a very good one. :)

Comment: Thanks for the supportive comments. I only had to read the first one before I was searching Google for an online compiler. I found one(http://codepad.org/), and had just fixed all of my errors before coming back to find that John Kugelman already fixed them. Thanks guys!

Comment: John,  Eeeeks!  There are still errors with your code.  check it in your compiler.  I am not sure why there are upvotes at this point unless people's sympathies are overriding their analytical faculties.